# insert no obligation data in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

i want to insert no obligation data in a formulaire some of them are required and some are not, even i changed the champs non required in MySQL to **NULL**, still is required to insert it.

```
$NumCaution         = $_POST['NumCaution'];
$NumAppeloffre      = $_POST['NumAppeloffre'];
$dateheurAppeloffre = $_POST['dateheurAppeloffre'];
$statut             = $_POST['statut'];
$dureeCaution       = $_POST['dureeCaution'];
$Montant            = $_POST['Montant'];
$date               =$_POST['date'];
$Montant            = $_POST['Montant'];
$nomClient          = $_POST['nomClient'];
```

```
$query="insert into caution (NumCaution,NumAppeloffre,dateheurAppeloffre,
                            statut,dureeCaution,Montant,DateCaution,IdClient) 
        values ('$NumCaution','$NumAppeloffre','$dateheurAppeloffre',
                '$statut','$dureeCaution','$Montant','$date','$IdClient')";
```

Comment: I cannot replicate this observation (although there seem to be thousands of examples of how to do this correctly out there)

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: NULL values should not be quoted, actual values should. As suggested, use Prepared Statements and Parameter Binding to eliminate the need to quote your own variables, and it will take care of the null vs values for you. Here are the instructions for [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: "still is required to insert it" is not an error message. It might have been helpful if you included the table definition. "Even I changed...." but you didn't show us that code.

Answer (score 0):

```php
if ( isset($_POST['NumCaution']) && $_POST['NumCaution']) {
  $NumCaution = $_POST['NumCaution']; 
} else {
  $NumCaution = '';
}
```

```php
$query="insert into caution (
  NumCaution,
  NumAppeloffre,
  dateheurAppeloffre,
  statut,
  dureeCaution,
  Montant,
  DateCaution,
  IdClient
) 
values (
  '$NumCaution',
  '$NumAppeloffre',
  '$dateheurAppeloffre',
  '$statut',
  '$dureeCaution',
  '$Montant',
  '$date',
  '$IdClient'
)";
```

Please think about security